# boundary of $\{x\in M: f(x)>0\}\implies f(x)=0$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a **continuous** function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$, and $A=\{x\in M: f(x)>0\}$, I need to show that if $x\in \partial A$(boundary of $A$), then $f(x) = 0$.

I know that $\partial A$ is the set of all points $x$ such that $d(x,a)=0$ for $a\in A$. So if $x\in \partial A$ we have $d(x,a) = 0$. However, I cannot draw a conclusion that implies $f(a)=0$. I don't know how the distance function relates to $f$. Any ideas? Maybe using another definition of boundary?

Comment: Well, this is obviously false without more assumptions, like continuity of $f$.

Comment: @T.Bongers yes, it needs to be continuous, sorry

Comment: Have you tried arguing by contradiction? What if $f(x)>0$? $f(x)<0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this is not true if $f$ is not continuous:

let $f$ be defined on the real line to equal $1$ on $]0,1[$, $-1$ elsewhere, then $\partial{A}$ is the two points $0$ and $1$ but $f(0)=f(1)=-1$.

If $f$ is continuous, notice $A$ is an open set, hence does not contain its boundary. Now suppose there were some $x$ in $\partial{A}$ with $f(x)<0$. What does the definition of continuity tell you?

Comment: Which definition of continuity? That the inverse of an open set is open? I don't see how this helps

Comment: If f(x)>0, then there exists some neighborhood of x such that f(y)>0 for all y in that neighborhood (this is the continuity of f). But any neighborhood of x on the boundary of A intersects A: so f(x)=0 for any x on the boundary of A, otherwise we would have points y in A such that f(y)>0

Comment: Sorry all inequalities should be reversed